# Why Log4net does not log in PowerGUI?

Tags: powershell, console, log4net, powergui

I use log4net as logger and here is my appender:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender"
        type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
<threshold value="INFO"/>
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
</layout>
```

In my case I write a powershell commandlet and logs into the powershell, but not if I use the powergui. Should I use an other appender? Someone could help me mange that it logs in the power gui?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a ConsoleAppender defined which works under powershell but not powershell ise. What's going on with ISE that prevents log4net's ConsoleAppender from working?

Comment: You are correct, it happens also in the PowerShell ISe, I have not found a solution for that, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `log4net` is looking in the current working directory for the configuration file, but your working directory is different when you're in PowerGui vs. in the console.

Use `set-location` at the beginning of your script to change to the appropriate directory.

Comment: I did `set-location <MyApplicationDirectory>` but nothing special happened. Did I selected the wrong direcotry, which specific directory do I have to choose? Which files should be in their? Another smoother way does not exist? Maybe another appender which could manage this alone, without any movements by the user?